# Codeigniter php logout issue when clicked logout URL not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i m new to ci just working on the login & logout. When i try to logout it 
 shows url    is not found /loginController/logout 
 What is the problem ? Is it because of the session or did i miss something?

Here is my controller

```
<?php

 class loginController extends CI_Controller{    /**controller*/

 public function index(){
    $this->login();
 }
 public function login(){
    $this->load->view('login');
 }
  public function home(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged')){
        $this->load->view('main');
    } else {
        redirect('loginController/denied');
 } 
 }
 public function denied(){
    $this->load->view('denied_page');
 }
  public function login_validation()                             /**set rules*/
  {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 
  'Username',         'required|min_length[3]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 
  'Password',   'required|sha1|callback_password_check');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()){                      /** form valdation*/
        $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input ->post('username'),
        'logged' => 1
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('main');
        } else {

        $this->load->view('login');





      }
    }

    public function logout(){                //login
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login');
    }


    public function password_check(){

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->model('users');

    if($this->users->log_in($username, $password)){
        return True;
        }else{

   $this->form_validation->set_message('password_check',
 'Incorrect username or  password.');
        return False;
    }




  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's not conflicting route somewhere? Could you post the routes?

Comment: it is my routes $route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

change the code

```
public function logout(){                //login

    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login');
}
```

to

```
public function logout(){   

    $this->session->sess_destroy(); 
    redirect('loginController/login');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. load `$this->load->helper('url');` on the index function and change `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));` to `$this->load->helper(array('form'));` on your validation function.
2. when redirecting use `base_url()`
3. on function logout change the second line `redirect('login');` to `redirect(base_url('/'.get_class($this)));`

i hope it works and help you, just remember to read [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) and after logout the login page will be accessed via your index() function.

if that will not work just try to change base_url() to site_url() but you should know what is the differences.

Comment: `redirect('login')` is perfectly fine and, actually, how it should be done (if the routes allow it!). I don't see why 2) and especially why that terrible 3). without the routes used it's impossibile to tell what's wrong with the code

Comment: maybe you are right but i dont know how redirect behind the scene and how it treat parameter

Comment: Well, why not read the docs and the code then, instead of guessing answers?

Comment: well thanks for just saying that, here we go there are right answers above me

Comment: Its still not working on me and when i click logout it will redirect me to /localhost/files/index.phpcontroller/logout with no "/" between index.php and controller. There is a multiple choice error appear

Comment: i change point number 3, i hope its working now. if still not working please describe more about the error. i just want to help you :)